# What is the best way to do SELECT in SQLite with equals subqueries

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I do big query with few subqueries and unions:

```
public Cursor getCursor(int outlayType, long carId){

    String selection;
    String[] selectionArgs;

    if(outlayType>0){
        selection = "car_id=? and type=?";
        selectionArgs = new String[]{
           Long.toString(carId),Integer.toString(outlayType),
           Long.toString(carId),Integer.toString(outlayType),
           Long.toString(carId),Integer.toString(outlayType)};
    }else{
        selection = "car_id=?";
        selectionArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(carId), Long.toString(carId), Long.toString(carId)};
    }

String sql = "select (select count(*)+1 from outlays b where a.date < b.date and "+selection+") as countNum," +
        " id as _id, id, type, note, sum, date," +
        " odometer, unread, future, input_type, 0 as row_type " +
        " from outlays a where "+ selection +"  " +
    " union " +
        " select 0, 0, 0, 0, '', sum(sum), max(date)+2," +
        " 0, 0, 0, '', 1 as row_type" +
        " from outlays where "+ selection +" group by strftime('%Y-%m', date/1000, 'unixepoch')" +
    " order by 7 DESC";

return sqdb.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
}
```

It works perfect, but ...

You can see: few times I use same WHERE conditions. And this is not the end. The query will grow. And this conditions will be use again and again.

I want to use temp table like this:

```
public Cursor getCursor(int outlayType, long carId){

    String selection;
    String[] selectionArgs;

    if(outlayType>0){
        selection = "car_id=? and type=?";
        selectionArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(carId),Integer.toString(outlayType)};
    }else{
        selection = "car_id=?";
        selectionArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(carId)};
    }

    sqdb.execSQL("drop table if exists sub");

    sqdb.execSQL("create  temp table  sub " +
    "as select * from outlays where "+selection, selectionArgs);

    String sql = "select (select count(*)+1 from sub b where a.date < b.date) as countNum," +
        " id as _id, id, type, note, sum, date," +
        " odometer, unread, future, input_type, 0 as row_type " +
        " from sub a " +
          " union " +
        " select 0, 0, 0, 0, '', sum(sum), max(date)+2," +
        " 0, 0, 0, '', 1 as row_type" +
        " from sub group by strftime('%Y-%m', date/1000, 'unixepoch')" +
              "  " +
          " order by 7 DESC";


    return sqdb.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
```

It looks better (for me), but when I call Cursor.notifyDataSetChanged - it works wrong. Because the recreation of temp table is not called.

How can I do one subquery or one temp table in the same query for Cursor?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure what your ultimate goal is, but I was able to convert your first query into a correlated query.  That is where the subselect gets if values for a column from the main query.  The key is that the main query column MUST always be on the right side of the comparison operator in the subselect, so I reversed the dates and switch the comparison operator.

Using the following data as input:

1   1   1   note 1  1   20130601    6100    1   1       0   201306

2   2   2   note 2  2   20130701    72013   0   1       0   201307

3   3   3   note 3  3   20130715    4201    1   1   a   0   201307

4   3   3   note 4  4   20130318    68010   1   1       0   201303

5   1   1   note 5  5   20130615    37077   1   1       0   201306

I couldn't replicate the strftime with the tool is was using so I added the last column ym, which I believe is equivalent to your result of strftime for your group by.

Here's the SQL i came up with:

```
select (select count(*)+1 from outlays b where b.date1 > a.date1  and b.car_id=a.car_id) as countNum, 
id as _id, a.id, a.type, a.note, a.sum1, a.date1, a.odometer, a.unread, a.future, a.input_type, 0 as row_type, ym 
from outlays a where car_id= 1
union all
select 0, 0, 0, 0, '', sum(sum1), max(date1)+2, 0, 0, 0, ' ', 1 as row_type, ym from outlays group by ym  order by 7 DESC;
```

There are the data results:

```
    #| |.|.|.|.     |.|.       |.    |.|.|.|.|.     
-+-+-+-+-+------+-+--------+-----+-+-+-+-+------
1|0|0|0|0|      |5|20130717|0    |0|0| |1|201307
2|0|0|0|0|      |6|20130617|0    |0|0| |1|201306
3|1|5|5|1|note 5|5|20130615|37077|1|1| |0|201306
4|2|1|1|1|note 1|1|20130601|6100 |1|1| |0|201306
5|0|0|0|0|      |4|20130320|0    |0|0| |1|201303
```

Note in this particular case until I really know the goal, either UNION or UNION ALL can be used.

Some things I noted and changed a few in the above:

1. There probably isn't a column name issue here 'id as _id and id' with the exception that you are almost being reduntant, in the future just use _id.  Anyone maintaining the code will then understand it a bit quicker. Nice way to get around the _id requirement by android methods.
2. There is also an issue probably with a column names of 'sum', and 'date' since it is also a sql function or might be, or a reserved word in some language and if not, I would just avoid out of good database design.
3. FYI: Not that this one matters at all, but type isn't really descriptive, column names should be descriptive, so type should be type_ofwhat, but that only if you want to follow good database design.
4. In addition, since I didn't know your intent, I wasn't sure there were other columns that you would want to group by.  From my experience, typically there are.

   1. The two queries might be able to be one, again I'd need to know what the real intent is for the result and all columns therein.

Hope this helps.